# Updating a JSON object using JQuery error?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, updating

I am trying to update a JSON array of data that is being stored in localStorage but it keeps crashing for some reason and I dont know why. Below is the code:

```
this.setToken = function(newToken) {
        var settingsList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("settings"));
        var l = settingsList.length;
        for (var i=0; i < l; i++) {
            if (settingsList[i].token === "") {
                app.showAlert(newToken,"[TOKEN-DEBUG]");
                settingsList.[i].token = newToken;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    var settings = [{"token": ""}
                    ];
    window.localStorage.setItem("settings", JSON.stringify(settings));
```

It keeps erroring on the following line:

```
settingsList.[i].token = newToken;
```

Please can someone help me with this as its driving me crazy :S

Comment: post rendered json object code. BTW, which error do you have?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem seems to be a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot between the array variable and the index.

```
settingsList[i].token = newToken;
```

Comment: bloody one of those days today cant believe I missed that thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the dot `.`:

```
settingsList.[i].token = newToken;
```

Should be

```
settingsList[i].token = newToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

`settingsList.[i].token = newToken;`

**should be**

```
settingsList[i].token = newToken;
```